# Continuous minimax with linear objective and constraints

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming, minimax

How to solve the following minimax problem quickly? The variables are all continuous.

$$\max_{x_{1}, x_{4}, x_{5}} \min_{x_2,x_3} \vec{c}^{\intercal} \vec{x}$$

subject to the following constraints:
$$A\vec{x} \ge \vec{b}$$
$$\vec{x} \ge 0$$

where

$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1  &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 \\
    -1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 \\
    0  &  1 &  1 &  0 &  0 \\
    0  & -1 & -1 &  0 &  0 \\
    0  &  -1 &  0 &  0.4 &  0 \\
    0  &  0 &  -1 &  0 &  0.4 \\
    1  &  0 &  0 &  -1 &  -1 \\
    0  & -0.6 &  0 &  1 &  0 \\
    0  &  0 & -0.6 &  0 &  1
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\vec{b}^{\intercal} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 2 & -2 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 0.6 & 0.6
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\vec{c}^{\intercal} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -0.6 & -0.6 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

I tried to split the variables into two groups $x_1, x_4, x_5$ and $x_2, x_3$. And replace the inner minimization by its dual, which is a maximization. But that makes the objective function quadratic instead of linear:

$$
 \max_{x_1, x_4, x_5} \left( \max_{x_2, x_3}  
\vec{b}^{\intercal} \vec{y} - \vec{x}^{\intercal}A_{1,4,5}^{\intercal} \vec{y}
 \right)$$
where $A_{1,4,5}$ is same as $A$ except columns 2 and 3 are all zeros.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is stated correctly?  This is maximin instead of minimax.  Also, the first two constraints imply that $x_1=1$, so you can eliminate that variable.

Comment: Yes. $x_1 = 1$, $x_2 + x_3 = 2$ Exchanging the order of max and min should be fine in this case because it is a zero-sum game: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax_theorem

Comment: Maybe there is no deterministic answer: https://blogs.cornell.edu/info2040/2015/10/19/game-theory-in-rock-paper-scissors/ But a probabilistic approximation is good enough for me. Probably I can start from a random feasible point and then alternate the maximization and minimization steps. Stop when I reach a cycle of solutions. Then try another random initial point again to find all cycles of solutions.

Comment: @QuriousCube There is no feasible point. Please see my answer.

Comment: That is nice. That gets rid of one branch of the search tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is infeasible:

$(c_1,c_2) \Rightarrow x_1=1$

$(c_3,c_4) \Rightarrow x_2+x_3=2$

$(c_1,c_2,c_7) \Rightarrow x_4 + x_5 \le 2$

$(c_5,c_6) \Rightarrow -(x_2+x_3)+0.4(x_4+x_5) \ge 2 \text{ and so } (c_3,c_4,c_5,c_6)\Rightarrow x_4 + x_5 \ge 10$

The last two lines are not consistent. Note that we also obtain a conflict with $(c_8,c_9)$:

$(c_8,c_9) \Rightarrow -0.6(x_2+x_3)+(x_4+x_5) \ge 1.2 \text{ and so } (c_3,c_4,c_8,c_9)\Rightarrow x_4 + x_5 \ge 2.4$

Comment: How can a computer know that the problem is infeasible?

Comment: Never mind. Just have add slack and surplus variables and then solve the system of equality

Comment: @QuriousCube Once the problem is infeasible, you can use a feature of linear solvers called *conflict refiner* that gives you a minimal set of conflicting constraints. Gurobi calls this minimal set an [Irreducible Inconsistent Subsystem (IIS)](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/py_model_computeiis.html). I haven't used a solver for this problem though. I started to characterize the basic feasible solutions of the minimization part (which only has two variables $x_2$ and $x_3$) to subsequently solve the original problem, and then realized that it is infeasible.